# .NET Sign data with smartcard

Tags: .net, rsa, smartcard

I'm trying to use the following code to sign some data using a key stored in smartcard

`CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(1, "Advanced Card Systems CSP v3.0");
csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);`

the app work on the first time, but second time throws an exception while executing line "3".

the exception message is "The parameter is incorrect.".

Comment: Looks more like a specific problem of "Advanced Card Systems CSP v3.0". Did you try with other card and CSP?

Answer (score 1):

`ImportParameters` method have two reasons to throw this `CryptographicException`.

"The Cryptographic Service Provider (CSP) cannot be acquired". Another is "The parameters parameter has missing fields". See the below page for more information - [RSA CSP Import Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.importparameters.aspx). The first solution, try the below code and let me know the result.

`RSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = True`

The error message shows that CSP missed parameter fields. Please refer to the page and test the example - [Cryptography CSP Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cspparameters.aspx).